Where to get libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386?
Where to get libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 ? I'm using Ubuntu 24.04.
I'm actually trying to run Adobe Reader under Ubuntu 24.04, but failed. And I even did sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386, but still no luck to run Adobe Reader.
I even tried the solution sudo apt-get install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 suggested on stackoverflow, but:
E: Unable to locate package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0'

Finally, I noticed
ldd /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread | grep "not found"
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf2700000)
    libBIB.so => not found
    libBIBUtils.so => not found
    libACE.so => not found
    libAGM.so => not found
    libCoolType.so => not found
    libAXE8SharedExpat.so => not found
    libJP2K.so => not found
    libAdobeXMP.so => not found
    libicuuc.so.36 => not found
    libssl.so.0.9.8 => not found
    libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => not found
    libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libResAccess.so => not found

Anyway, how to successfully run Acrobat Reader on Ubuntu 24.04?
Cheers

I doubt you're going to get much help here, considering that the latest version of acroread is 11 years old. I did find this recent tutorial - https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux - but I would not do it.

Why would you ever consider a i386 version and what is wrong with acrordrdc?

A version of Evince should already be installed.  You don't need the Adobe Reader anymore.  Even Chrome/Chromium and Microsoft's fork Edge will read PDF files.

Well. Some times, the encrypted .pdf file requires Adobe Reader. Please refer to: https://imgur.com/a/HDRGTnD

Funny story: I found this page because I tried to install Acrobat Reader 9 after upgrading to ubuntu 2024.04,... looking for libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386.

I've got acroread working after installing libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0 from Debian Bookworm:
wget http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gdk-pixbuf-xlib/libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0_2.40.2-2_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0_2.40.2-2_i386.deb


The above solution from @petrnik worked for me, using same configuration, ubuntu 24.04 and  latest acroread. Had exactly the same issues detailed in this thread. Now just receiving following errors, else works fine ```(acroread:19710): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:17:16.496: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
(acroread:19710): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:17:16.496: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",```

Well, acroread 32bit version worked fine until the upgrade to Ubuntu 24, which i for one would have liked to continue.
Evince, Atril and the like don't have the full function set of acroread. In my case i need to see an embedded XML in a PDF/A.
acrordrdc in wine i'll try, but i think that's a crutch.
For acrordrdc on Snap i won't start with the Snap system, period.
That's what's wrong.
Best regards.

I found Okular which fits my needs.
